# How to fix "warning: symbolic ref is dangling" in git

Tags: git, repository

Recently I started to notice that on one of my git repositories, any git command I run, I get the following warning:

`warning: symbolic ref is dangling: refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`

**What does this mean and how do I fix it?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### How to fix it

Because this particular symbolic ref is not useful anyway, I recommend just deleting it:

```
git remote set-head origin --delete
```

If you like having this useless symbolic ref, you can have your Git auto-update it instead:

```
git remote set-head origin --auto
```

This will have your Git call up the other Git over at `origin`, ask it what its current branch is *now*, and update your symbolic-ref `origin/HEAD` appropriately.

If updating it like this doesn't fix it, don't worry: it's probably not actually broken and will "self heal" eventually.  In any case, it is, in my opinion, useless anyway, so even if it *is* broken, this doesn't hurt anything.

#### About refs

Let's start by noting what a *ref* is:

- A ref, or reference, is a name.  There are some restrictions on the name (see [the `git check-ref-format` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format), but it's mostly just a string of letters and digits and such, with what we can hope spell out a name that means something to you.

  For instance, a branch name is a ref.  So is a tag name.
- Most of these names actually start with `refs/`.  The only ones that don't are not always called *refs* (Git is not completely consistent about this): they're the special names `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, and so on.  (They are all either `HEAD` itself, which is the most special of all, or end in `_HEAD`.  They should always be spelled out in all uppercase like this.)
- Refs are divided into [*namespaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).  Two that you use all the time are the *branch* namespace, which is every ref whose spelling starts with `refs/heads/`, and the *tag* namespace, which is every ref whose name starts with `refs/tags/`.  There is a third one you also use all the time: *remote-tracking names* are refs whose name starts with `refs/remotes/`.  After the word `remotes` and its trailing slash, Git adds the name of the remote in question, such as `origin`, and another trailing slash.

Hence *ref* is simply the general form of any branch or tag or remote-tracking name, or any other name, in Git.  There are some less-frequently-used ones, and internal ones, like `refs/stash` for the `git stash` command, `refs/bisect/` for `git bisect`, and so on; normally you don't see these at all.

You do see branch, tag, and remote-tracking names, but Git normally *strips off* the "namespace" part of the name:

- `master` is really `refs/heads/master`, but Git stripped off the `refs/heads/` part.
- `v1.2` is really `refs/tags/v1.2`, but Git stripped off the `refs/tags/` part.
- `origin/master` is really `refs/remotes/origin/master`, but Git stripped off the `refs/remotes/` part.

Sometimes Git strips only the `refs/` part from remote-tracking names.  It's not at all clear why, but `git branch -a` does this.  That's why you see `remotes/origin/master` here.  Compare with `git branch -r`, where you see only `origin/master`.  In any case, this is a valid way to express each name, because there is a six-step rule for *resolving* any name you give, as shown in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), and three of the steps involve trying to stick `refs/remotes` or `refs/heads` or `refs/tags` in front of any name you give.  We'll get back to this in a moment.

Most refs store exactly one thing: a hash ID.  For branch names and remote-tracking names, that hash ID must be a *commit* hash ID.  For tags, it's usually either a commit hash ID, or the hash ID of an *annotated tag object*, which then stores the commit hash ID.  This extra step—going through the tag object—allows you to write an *annotated* tag, or a tag with a message.

But some refs are *symbolic* refs.  What this means is that instead of storing a hash ID, they store the *name of some other ref*.  The most common one—in fact, the only *useful* one, in my opinion—is the very special `HEAD` ref.<sup>1</sup>

`HEAD` normally contains the name of a branch.  That is, if you look at the actual file `.git/HEAD`, you'll see, e.g.:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

In other words, the *name* `HEAD` simply holds the *branch name* `master`.  What this means is that `master` is the *current* branch.  This is how Git implements an attached HEAD.  Hence a *detached* HEAD is just the case where `HEAD` holds a commit hash ID instead of a branch name.  That's really all there is to attached vs detached HEAD.  Git just asks itself: *Does `HEAD` hold a branch name?*  If so, that branch is the *current branch* and the commit hash ID stored in that branch name is the *current commit*.  If not, `HEAD` holds a commit hash ID, and that hash ID is the current commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>`HEAD` is very special because, among other things, if the file goes missing, Git will stop believing that the repository *is* a repository!  Never remove `.git/HEAD`.  If, after a computer crash, you need to recover a repository whose `HEAD` file has gone missing, you can try creating one containing `ref: ref/heads/master` and see if that allows you to proceed.  This happens surprisingly often after a crash because `HEAD` is such a relatively active file, and one method computer systems use to recover after a crash is simply to *remove* any damaged file.

---

#### What it all means

In general, a ref *must* resolve to a commit or other hash ID, for some valid, existing, internal Git object.<sup>2</sup>  For instance, a branch name like `master` is only allowed to *exist* if it holds the hash ID of some existing, valid commit.

If a ref holds the name of some other ref, that other ref needs to exist, and resolve to a valid hash ID.<sup>3</sup>  If the other ref *doesn't* exist, though, we can say that the symbolic ref is *dangling*.

That's what this means:

> ```
> warning: symbolic ref is dangling: refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
> ```

Your existing `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is a symbolic ref—all remote-tracking `remote/HEAD` names are symbolic refs after all—but whatever name it contains, that *name* doesn't exist.

**Note**: There is a situation in which your own `HEAD` is a dangling symbolic reference.  This occurs normally in a new, totally-empty repository.  `HEAD` *must* exist, so it does.  It should contain the name of a branch, so it contains `ref: refs/heads/master`.  It is a symbolic ref, saying that you are on branch `master`.  But this is a new, totally-empty repository.  There are no valid commits in it!  The *branch name* `master` *cannot* exist, because a branch name is required to hold the hash ID of a valid, existing commit, and there are none.  So `master` itself, the branch name, simply doesn't exist.  This makes `HEAD` a dangling symref.

Making the first commit *creates* the name `master`, resolving the situation.  So it resolves all on its own, and there's nothing wrong with this situation.  Hence a dangling symbolic ref is not harmful.  This is especially true of `HEAD` (where Git won't complain about the dangling symbolic ref), but it's true of `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` too: these are all harmless.  Unlike the special case for `HEAD`, though, they're not *useful*.

---

<sup>2</sup>This is usually a commit, but tags can point to any of Git's four internal object types.  They need to be able to point to annotated tag objects, of course, so that you can have annotated tags.  Git just takes away all restrictions here though, which lets them point to tree or blob objects too.

<sup>3</sup>Note that the introduction of symbolic references, which are resolved at reference-look-up-time, also introduces the possibility of loops.  The name *A* might refer to the name *B*, with the name *B* referring to *C*, and then *C* could refer back to *A*.  How will you resolve this?

Exercise: how does git resolve this?  It's relatively easy to detect a self-loop: if the name *tumbolia* says *my answer is obtained by looking up the name "tumbolia"*, you can immediately see, while looking up "tumbolia", that you'll loop or recurse forever looking yourself up over and over.  But what about long chains of names?

Exercise: Your operating system may provide *symbolic links* or *symlinks*, which are files whose contents are other files' names.  If so, how does your OS prevent or detect symbolic link loops?  (Git used to implement symbolic refs via symlinks.  This changed when Git added Windows support, since many Windows systems don't offer symlinks.)

---

#### Why this isn't useful, unless you think it is

Let's go back to the six-step process Git uses for resolving a name that you type in.  For instance, suppose you run:

```
git rev-parse master
```

Try this out.  Try running `git rev-parse` with various names, and also with ranges like `master..develop`, and with names with operators added, like `master~2`.  Then go look at [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) again, and find this:

> 1. If **`$GIT_DIR/<refname>`** exists, that is what you mean (this is
>      usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`
>      and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
> 2. otherwise, **`refs/<refname>`** if it exists;
> 3. otherwise, **`refs/tags/<refname>`** if it exists;
> 4. otherwise, **`refs/heads/<refname>`** if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, **`refs/remotes/<refname>`** if it exists;

Three of these five rules make it possible to just write `master` or `v1.2` or `origin/master`.  Rule #5 takes care of `origin/master`: since `refs/heads/origin/master` exists, if you run `git rev-parse origin/master` and rules 1 through 4 don't work, rule 5 works and that's where `git rev-parse` stops with a valid commit hash ID.  So that's what `git rev-parse` prints.

Rule #4 handles branch names.  Rule #3 handles tag names.  Note that rule #3 means that if you create a *tag* named `master`, the *tag* overrides the *branch*, in most cases.<sup>4</sup>  If you're in this situation, you can make use of rule #2, by writing `heads/master` or `tags/master`.

But that leaves out one last rule.  Here it is:

> 6. otherwise, **`refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD`** if it exists.

This particular rule means that you can run:

```
git rev-parse origin
```

Git will try the other five steps, all of which will fail, and then will try parsing `origin` as if you'd written `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.  If this name exists *and* can be resolved to a hash ID, that's the hash ID you will get.

What all this boils down to in the end is that you can use the name of a *remote* as shorthand for *the value of the remote-tracking name that my Git has in its symbolic ref under that remote's `HEAD`*.  That is, if you have remotes named `r1`, `r2`, and `r3`, you can use the name `r2` instead of writing out `refs/remotes/r2/HEAD` (which works without needing the six-step process) or `r2/HEAD` (which works by using step #5).

How often do you, or anyone, actually use this?  That's how useful these symbolic refs are.  No one I know uses it, ever, so as far as I can tell, it's not useful.

---

<sup>4</sup>Commands that assume, or first try, a name as a *branch* name will pick the *branch* meaning instead.  For instance, `git checkout master` will check out the *branch*.  But `git rev-parse master` doesn't assume a branch name, so it parses the *tag*, finding it in step 3 and never moving to step 4.

It's therefore unwise to use the same name as both a branch and tag name.  Git has rules that will pick one or the other, but they may not match your personal expectations!

Comment: (Thanks to KeddyAssociates for the swapped-parameters-in-command edit/fix)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error when I tried to use a custom symbolic ref to point to a branch.[1] I used something like this:

```
$ git symbolic-ref issue-key feature
```

But then when I wanted to use it I got that “dangling” error:

```
$ git rev-parse issue-key
warning: ignoring dangling symref issue-key
issue-key
warning: ignoring dangling symref issue-key
fatal: ambiguous argument 'issue-key': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

It turned out that I needed to give the full ref of the branch that I wanted to point to: `refs/heads/feature`. And I probably also should use a branch symbolic ref. So what I wanted was:

```
$ git symbolic-ref refs/heads/issue-key refs/heads/feature
```

#### Deleting the old (unwanted) symbolic ref

I didn’t want the `issue-key` (no ref path). It turns out that it is stored in `.git` (alongside other symbolic refs like `HEAD`) when it’s created without the full ref. But I wasn’t able to delete it through `git symbolic-ref`:

```
$ git symbolic-ref --delete NRS-4643
error: refusing to update ref with bad name 'issue-key'
```

So I just deleted it manually:

```
$ rm .git/issue-key
```

#### Notes

1. Context: I had a branch `feature` which was used in a PR so I couldn’t change the name. But I wanted (in hindsight) to include the issue key in the branch name. So I wanted to create a ref that pointed to the PR branch.[2]
2. Note that I don’t know if this is something that one is “supposed to” use symbolic refs for. I’ve only just recently discovered it.